# XPathExpression to select child attribute value ignoring the namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am quite new to work on the XPathExpression and I am trying to build an expression to retrieve the attribute values into my custom java object i.e. Message. Below is the dummy XML where it will have many **message** nodes.

My Java code should read this XML and correspondingly it creates a list of Java objects for **messages**.

Here is the condition based on which I am trying build an XpathExpression.

1. Within this Xpath **jobReport/records/record/messages** check if **title** has the value **TestCompany**. If there is any other company message should be skipped

I am using the below Xpath Expression but it failing to return the data because of the Namespace data. Now I need to skip these name space using an expression and get the **Title** value.

1. **jobReport/records/record/messages/*[local-name()='aa:title']**
2. **jobReport/records/record/messages/*[local-name()='aa:title'/text()='TestCompany']**
3. **//*[local-name()='aa:title'/text()='TestCompany']**

j

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobReport>
    <jobID>123515412512221</jobID>
    <rundate>2016-09-16</rundate>
    <startTime>13:09:49</startTime>
    <endTime>13:10:39</endTime>
    <containsErrors>false</containsErrors>
    <records>
        <record>
            <recordid>20160920001</recordid>
            <primaryfilename>hello.pdf</primaryfilename>
            <result>
                <status>OK</status>
                <errorcode />
            </result>
            <messages>
                <aa:title xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/example/test/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="DummyProject/2016-04">TestCompany</aa:title>
                <aa:messageid xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/example/test/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="OP360CustomerArchive/2016-04">30.02.02.15.01</aa:messageid>
                <aa:messagefrom xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/example/test/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="OP360CustomerArchive/2016-04">FI</aa:messagefrom>
                <aa:messageto
                    xmlns="http://www.op.fi/hallintapalvelut/dokumenttirajapinta/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="OP360CustomerArchive/2016-04">keijo</aa:messageto>
                <aa:mailid
                    xmlns="http://www.op.fi/hallintapalvelut/dokumenttirajapinta/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="OP360CustomerArchive/2016-04">agreement</aa:mailid>
                <aa:phonenumber
                    xmlns="http://www.op.fi/hallintapalvelut/dokumenttirajapinta/xml/"
                    xmlns:aa="OP360CustomerArchive/2016-04">xml-tuote</aa:phonenumber>
            </messages>
        </record>
    </records>
</jobReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `local-name()` of an element will not include the namespace prefix.

So, rather than `*[local-name()='aa:title']`, use `*[local-name()='title']`.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not giving me what I am looking for. I tried using the below expression but that just giving me the namespace and not the value i.e. **TestCompany**

**jobReport/records/record/messages/*[local-name()='alertmethod']**

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, Correcting the expression

**/jobReport/records/record/messages/*[local-name()='title']**

Comment: **Check more carefully:**  `/jobReport/records/record/messages/*[local-name()='title']` [***does select `aa:title` as shown here***](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/3b8b3385d6efdc4ec48cc0bdac83468e).